# Android preference screen, fullscreen only?

Tags: java, android, xml, preferences, sharedpreferences

I have a fully functioning Preferences screen in android set to landscape.
What I would like to do is have it only take up half the screen horizontally.

Any ideas how to do it? my code snippets are below:

```
     addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
```

xml:

```
<PreferenceCategory
            android:title="User Preferences">
     <ListPreference
            android:name="BallDisplayPreference"
            android:key="BallPref"
            android:summary="Show numbers or notes on balls"
            android:title="Balls"
            android:defaultValue="Fret"
            android:entries="@array/listArray"
            android:entryValues="@array/listValues"  />
   </PreferenceCategory>
```

Thanks guys,

Ben

Answer (score 1):

What about using a normal activity, with a [PreferenceFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceFragment.html) in one half, and in the other half anything you like?